# How to use XML-RPC in CodeIgniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I’m currently migrating my project from CodeIgniter 3 to CodeIgniter 4. In CodeIgniter 3, I was using the built-in XML-RPC libraries, but it seems that these libraries are not included in CodeIgniter 4.

I tried to use the CodeIgniter 3 XML-RPC libraries by changing the namespace according to CodeIgniter 4, but when I use them, I get the error “This is not a known method for this XML-RPC Server”.

Here is my controller code:

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use App\Models\Apprequest_model;
use Config\Services;

class Apprequest extends Controller
{
    const ERROR_BAD_PARAMETER = 1;
    const ERROR_DATA_NOT_EXIST = 2;

    protected $apprequestModel;
    protected $xmlrpc;
    protected $xmlrpcs;

    public function index()
    {
        $this->xmlrpc = new \App\Libraries\Xmlrpc();
        $this->xmlrpcs = new \App\Libraries\Xmlrpcs();

        $this->apprequestModel = new Apprequest_model();
        
        $config['functions']['xmlrpc_server.process'] = array('function' => 'xmlrpc_server.process');
        $config['functions']['apprequest.get_app_version'] = array('function' => 'apprequest.get_app_version');

        $this->xmlrpcs->initialize($config);
        $this->xmlrpcs->serve();
    }

    public function get_app_version($request)
    {
        $fcmModel = new \App\Models\Fcm_model();
        $error_code = 0;
        $array = array();
        
         .........
         .........

        $array = $this->apprequestModel->getAppVersion($platform);

        // Data not found error, error code: 2
        if (empty($array)) {
            $array = [];
            $error_code = 2;
        }
        $array['error_code'] = $error_code;
        $data = array($array, 'struct');
        $response = $data;

        return  $this->xmlrpc->send_response($response);
    }
}
```

And here is the XML-RPC request that I’m sending to the server:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
  <methodName>apprequest.get_app_version</methodName>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value><string>iOS</string></value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodCall>
```

But the response I’m getting is: “This is not a known method for this XML-RPC Server”

Is there a way to use the CodeIgniter 3 XML-RPC libraries in CodeIgniter 4, or is there an alternative solution for using XML-RPC in CodeIgniter 4? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter 4 doesn't natively support XML-RPC out of the box. CodeIgniter 4 focuses more on modern PHP practices and standards, and XML-RPC is a relatively older technology.

However, if you still want to integrate XML-RPC functionality into a CodeIgniter 4 project, you might need to do some manual integration work. Here's a general outline of the steps you would need to follow:

Install CodeIgniter 4: If you haven't already, you need to install and set up CodeIgniter 4 in your project directory.

Create XML-RPC Library: You'll need to create a custom library or class to handle XML-RPC communication. In the app/Libraries directory, you can create a new file, e.g., XmlRpcClient.php, and define your XML-RPC client code there. You can use PHP's built-in XML-RPC functions or a third-party library.

Configure Autoloading: You need to configure the autoloading of your custom library. Open the app/Config/Autoload.php file and add your library to the classmap array.

Controller Integration: Create a new controller or use an existing one to handle XML-RPC requests. In your controller method, use the XML-RPC client library to process the incoming XML-RPC requests and provide appropriate responses.